# Python Filepaths

Tags: python, escaping

I am trying to build a simple script which must be able to navigate through directories, sub-directories, and sub-sub-directories, and I have never done it before.

Why does this code generate the output that it does--with the double-backslash?  Also, what should my code be doing, given my objectives?

I believe my objective is to maintain the single backslash, but I am unsure.  All I know is I will be bouncing between different levels within the same directory--into sub-directories and sub-sub-directories.  Trying to work through the program further, I believe I am running into errors by trying to look for files with filepaths that contain double backslashes.

```
import os, shutil, time

mdir = 'C:\\Users\Dev\Desktop\Python_Test'
dirlist = [(mdir + '\\' + i) for i in os.listdir(mdir) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(mdir, i))]

print dirlist
```

Output:

```
['C:\\Users\\Dev\\Desktop\\Python_Test\\Dir 1',
 'C:\\Users\\Dev\\Desktop\\Python_Test\\Dir 2']
```

Comment: Try using [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) to process all sub-directories of a given path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double backslash is there because you're calling `print` on a list, which prints the `repr` of the list's elements:

```
>>> l = ['C:\\Users\\Dev\\Desktop\\Python_Test\\Dir 1',
...      'C:\\Users\\Dev\\Desktop\\Python_Test\\Dir 2']
>>> for x in l:
...     print(repr(x))
...     
'C:\\Users\\Dev\\Desktop\\Python_Test\\Dir 1'
'C:\\Users\\Dev\\Desktop\\Python_Test\\Dir 2'
```

`repr` is also giving you the quotes around the strings. The idea is that the output of `repr` (for simple types like `str`) can be fed back to the Python interpreter directly. To print without quotes and with single backslashes, print the elements separately:

```
>>> for x in l:
...     print(x)
...     
C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\Python_Test\Dir 1
C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\Python_Test\Dir 2
```

Use this form when communicating with the outside world.

Btw., for walking directory hierarchies, use [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) and for constructing paths, use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Answer (score 0):

Use the os.walk intrinsic.  It's great!

```
>>> import os
>>> os.walk('.')
<generator object walk at 0x163891E8>
>>> listWalk = []
>>> for items in os.walk('.'):
...     listWalk.append(items)
...     
>>> listWalk
```

listWalk will now contain a list of 3-part items:  [thisDir, listDirs, listFiles]

1. thisDir is the string of the directory that the walk is examining
2. listDirs is a list of the string of Directory names inside of
   thisDir
3. listFiles is a list of the strings of file names inside thisDir

You can iterate or process the returned list, and pluck out whatever you need.

Comment: I would not actually create such a list prior to doing the actual walking, though.